# How to check if button is selected or not

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I Have to check if a css button is selected, or not.

It is  has two states Off = "The Customer is NOT over 18" , On ="The Customer is over 18" it is driven by css.

I am having an issues trying to catch the status, to decide if my script has to click on it or not. How do i check this ?

this is the xpath i am using to currently click it / off on :

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//i[contains(@class,'c-option__button i-icon i-icon--plus-18-movie')]"));
```

and `uib-tooltip="The Customer is NOT over 18">` is the text that changes.

But need a check before it, whether i need to click or not.

```
<age-question-button class="ng-scope ng-isolate-scope" state="qc.answer[question.name]" icon="plus-18-movie" active-text="The Customer is over 18" inactive-text="The Customer is NOT over 18" ng-repeat="question in qc.questionsList track by question.name" audit="cc.utils.audit(qc.answer[question.name] ? question.auditInactive : question.auditActive)">
<label class="c-option u-p-0 u-ml-md u-pull-left" tooltip-append-to-body="true" uib-tooltip="The Customer is over 18">
<input class="ng-untouched ng-valid ng-dirty ng-valid-parse" ng-model="state" ng-change="audit()" style="" type="checkbox">
<i class="c-option__button i-icon i-icon--plus-18-movie"></i>
</label>

<label class="c-option u-p-0 u-ml-md u-pull-left" tooltip-append-to-body="true" uib-tooltip="The Customer is NOT over 18">
<input class="ng-untouched ng-valid ng-dirty ng-valid-parse" ng-model="state" ng-change="audit()" style="" type="checkbox">
<i class="c-option__button i-icon i-icon--plus-18-movie"></i>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To check before whether **`The Customer is over 18`** or not, you can use this code block :

```
if(driver.findElement(By.tagName("age-question-button")).getAttribute("active-text").contains("NOT"))
    System.out.println("The Customer is NOT over 18");
else
    System.out.println("The Customer is over 18");
```

Comment: Sorry DebanjanB, but i missed part of the code in my post ...
You code works, for the bit i first posted.

Comment: Can you update in brief what exactly you are you looking for?

Comment: have just made a new post, which explains my question properly.
thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Do you need to check whether the element is visible first? If so:

```
driver.findElement(By.id("idOfElement")).isDisplayed();
```

As per the post below, you should probably open a new question for the second part of your issue as it wasn't specified originally